# Customizing Maven Reporting Plugins for a Confluence Wiki

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin, confluence

I've developed a Maven reporting plugin for internal use at our company.  It's designed to work in standalone mode so that it can be run against a given project without having to be configured in the `<reporting>` section of the pom.

However, the format of the document is currently in xhtml and all of our project docs are currently stored on Confluence.  It would be a great convenience to generate the document in Confluence markup.  There already exist `ConfluenceSink` and `ConfluenceSinkFactory` classes that would generate the proper markup, but I don't see an obvious way to set the sinks used by subclasses of `AbstractMavenReport`.

The approach I'm currently taking is:

- Overriding the `execute` method as this currently hardcodes the use of `SiteRendererSink`, which outputs xhtml.
- Finding an alternative to `SiteRenderer.generateDocument()`, as this method requires the above-mentioned `SiteRendererSink`.

Has anyone tackled these issues?  Appreciate the feedback.

Finally, can I just note for the record that the API documentation for Maven is atrocious?  I don't need a hand-holding tutorial -- just some basic javadocs and a sprinkling of insightful comments would be a huge help in getting anything done with this codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to cook up a working solution.  I was on the right track, I was just making things more complicated than they needed to be -- again, better documentation would have saved me sifting through various plugins looking for an example.

So, if anyone wants to do something similar, first get your plugin working at producing xhtml.  I found [this link](http://teleal.org/weblog/software/Howto%20write%20a%20Maven%20report%20plugin.html) to be fairly helpful in that regard.  To change the output format, you'll have to override the `execute()` method and provide the `generate()` method with the appropriate `Sink` and `SinkFactory` implementations.

Here's an example for output in Confluence markup:

```
@Override
public void execute()
    throws MojoExecutionException
{
    try
    {
        File outputDirectory = new File(getOutputDirectory());

        String filename = getOutputName() + ".cf";

        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

        ConfluenceSinkFactory factory = new ConfluenceSinkFactory();
        Sink sink = factory.createSink(outputDirectory, filename);

        generate(sink, factory, locale);
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        throw new MojoExecutionException(e);
    }
    catch ( MavenReportException e )
    {
        throw new MojoExecutionException(e);
    }
}
```